# How to dock/undock Widget (QDockWidget?)?

Tags: qt4, qdockwidget

I have a widget with 4 QGraphicsViews and I want them to be dockable. I've put a QGraphicsView in a QDockWidget. Then I was able to undock the view, but I don't know how to dock the view back, where it was. At the begin, there is a bar with an undock button, but when the widget is undocked, then this bar is gone.

What do I need to do, to dock the widget on it's original/starting position? 
Or is this QDockWidget not for things like that? 
I would be very grateful  for some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drag the widget back to its starting position, and the main window should grab it automatically. If this doesn't work for you, take a look at the `Dock Widgets` example program (Qt Creator -> Help -> Contents -> Tutorials and Examples -> Main Window Examples -> Dock Widgets). If even this example program doesn't work, then something is wrong with your Qt installation!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but I don't want to drag it back. I want to press a button and then it gets docked back. First button-press undocks the view and the second it docks back.

Comment: Thats ok. but what if you want to dock it to the right or bottom? Or any other? setfloating has no more parameters.